# Can't cast 2nd Enum value to int?

Tags: c#

I don't get this.  I was able to cast my first enum value to int but not the second?

```
public enum PayPalTransactionType
{
    Authorization = 0, // Debit
    Capture = 1, // Credit
    Refund = 2,
    Void = 3
}

public string GetPayPalTransCode(PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType payPalTransactionType)
{
    string actionCode = string.Empty;

    switch (payPalTransactionType)
    {
        case (int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization:
            actionCode = "Debit";
            break;
        case (int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture:
            actionCode = "Credit";
            break;
    }

    return actionCode;
}
```

on my 2nd case statement I get this casting error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `int`
>   to `PayPalTransactionType`. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Comment: Please edit your question to put all the code in a code block, it is confusing right now. Thanks

Comment: Why are you casting the `enum` to an `int` in your case statements?  You actually don't need to cast those at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why are you trying to cast in the first place? Just leave it as the enum value everywhere:

```
public string GetPayPalTransCode
    (PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType payPalTransactionType)
{
    string actionCode = string.Empty;

    switch (payPalTransactionType)
    {
        case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization:
            actionCode = "Debit";
            break;
        case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture:
            actionCode = "Credit";
            break;
    }

    return actionCode;
}
```

Additionally, I'd have an explicit default action for unrecognised codes, and just return directly:

```
public string GetPayPalTransCode
    (PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType payPalTransactionType)
{
    switch (payPalTransactionType)
    {
        case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization:
            return "Debit";
        case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture:
            return "Credit";
        default:
            return ""; // Or throw an exception if this represents an error
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `Dictionary<PayPalTransactionType, string>`.

Answer (score 6):

Why are you casting to `int` at all? The thing you are `switch`ing on is already of the enum type!

Answer (score 4):

As to the other part of the question, the reason the first cast is working is because an implicit cast from a constant int 0 to an enum type always works, whereas the other attempted cast is from a non-zero int value.

Answer (score 2):

why for god's sake are you doing a cast??

```
public string GetPayPalTransCode(PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType payPalTransactionType)
{
    switch (payPalTransactionType)
    {
        case (int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization:
            break;
        case (int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture:
            break;
    }
}
```

bascially same type in here, isn't it?! you want to compare enum against enum, don't you?

just do

```
public string GetPayPalTransCode(PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType payPalTransactionType)
{
    // ...
    switch (payPalTransactionType)
    {
        case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization:
            break;
        case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture:
            break;
    }
    // ...
}
```

btw - it's not best practice to assign `PayPalTransactionType.Authorization` to `0`. `0` should be used for parsing-fallbacks!

**edit:**
your code would be correct if you do

```
public string GetPayPalTransCode(PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType payPalTransactionType)
{
    switch ((int)payPalTransactionType)
    {
        case (int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization:
            break;
        case (int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture:
            break;
    }
}
```

which is quite ...!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `(int)` casts in your case statements. The switch can handle the enum values.

Since the switch is on `PayPalTransactionType', values of that type should be used in the case statements.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need these casts in the first place. Just make it `case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you casting it to an int the first place.? Just do the case statements using the enumerated type.

If you are really just looking up a string a better method would be an array of strings that you index by the enumerated type. That would be faster, less code and easier to maintain.

So something like this:

```
public enum PayPalTransactionType
{
  Authorization = 0, // Debit 
  Capture = 1, // Credit 
  Refund = 2,
  Void = 3,
  Max  // This must always be the last type and is used just as a marker.
}
string[] ActionCode = new string[(int)PayPalTransactionType.Max] { "Debit", "Credit", "Refund", "Void" };


public string GetPayPalTransCode(PayPalTransactionType payPalTransactionType)
{
  return ActionCode[(int)payPalTransactionType];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the casts to `int`. Just use the enum directly.

```
switch (payPalTransactionType)
{
    case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization:
        actionCode = "Debit";
        break;
    case PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture:
        actionCode = "Credit";
        break;
}
```

The error occurs because your trying to *implicitly* convert `payPalTransactionType` to `int`. Maybe this will enlighten your problem:

```
switch ((int)payPalTransactionType)
{
    case (int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Authorization:
        actionCode = "Debit";
        break;
    case (int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture:
        actionCode = "Credit";
        break;
}
```

This first cast allows you to `switch` on `int`s instead of `PayPalTransactionType`s. Since the switch statement supports enums, you don't need this cast.

Answer (score 0):

Tim,

I am not a Java/C# expert, but here is my 2 cents on the code block above ...

1. If you're using an enum, why do you need to have an int value, if you do, then do something like:

   public enum PayPalTransactionType
   {
       Authorization(0, Debit),
       Capture(1, Credit),
       Refund(3, null),
       Void(4. null);

   ```
   private final int code;

   public int getCode()
   {return(code);}

   private PayPalTransactionType(final int code, final TransactionType transactionType)
   {
      this.code = code;
      this.transactionType = transactionType;
   }

   private TransactionType getTransactionType()
   {return(transactionType);}
   ```

   }

public enum TransactionType
{
   Credit("Funds are added to the specified account."),
   Debit("funds are deducted from the specified account.");

private final String description;

public String getDescription()
   {return(description);}

private TransactionType(final String description)
   {this.description = description;}
}

2. Switches are useful for a very small amount of cases.  You can simply do this:

   final PayPalTransactionType payPalTransactionType = PayPalTransactionType.Authorization;// this is just an example of the parameter you'd be passing in.

   payPalTransactionType.getTransactionType();// an emum is a static database, simply store other things that are related to this value.

Walter

Answer (score 0):

It's not the cast to int that's giving you a problem.  Its the cast of `(int)PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType.Capture` (which is an int) back to PayPalServiceBase.PayPalTransactionType that's the problem.